# 404 redirect to sub URLs from .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to redirect some sub url roots to a 404 not found page on my website.

For example: I need a .htaccess code that can redirect category 1 and sub urls such as mywebstiem.com/kategori1/xxx,yy,xx to a 404 page.

**I want to apply this to only 1 category. not to all categories!**

The infrastructure of my site: WordPress.

For example: I need a .htaccess code that can redirect category 1 and sub urls such as mywebstiem.com/kategori1/xxx,yy,xx to a 404 page.

Comment: `RedirectMatch 404 ^/kategori1/(.*)$` or works also `RedirectMatch 404 ^/kategori1(.*)$`

Comment: Is `xxx,yy,xx` a particular URL _pattern_?